# Laravel VerifyController does not exist

Tags: laravel-5.8

when write artisan command to see route list then saw verifyController does not exist

```
php artisan route:list
Class App\Http\Controllers\VerifyController does not exist
```

How can i solve this problem?Help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have "Route::get('some-route', 'VerifyController');" in routes/web.php and dont have VerifyController.php in App/Http/Controllers

You should create "VerifyController.php" or remove Route::get('some-route', 'VerifyController');" this line from routes/web.php

Comment: Also you can try this commands: "php artisan cache:clear" & "php artisan route:cache"

Comment: Route defiened in route/api.php file.Here is the route ```Route::resource('/users', 'userController');```.why need VerifyController.php file.@Dato Sarishvili